# Horizontal Multiple item slider with 1 item scroll in HTML/CSS (No Plugin) with Bootstrap 3.3.+

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, slideshow, horizontal-scrolling

Check this example http://www.bootply.com/94452

I need to make similarly horizontal multi item slider without using plugin. i want to make it in html css and js/jquery.

Above slider does not work well when copied it and tried, it slides all item on screen then at the end scrolled only once.

I want to slide item 1 by 1.

After the last item there should be the first in other words slides should be circularly.

Items containing images and other contents.
Here is code i tried.

```
<style>
    @import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -25%; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  25%; }
    .carousel-inner .prev        { left: -25%; }
    .carousel-control            { width:  4%; }
    .carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {margin-left:15px;background-image:none;}
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h3>Bootstrap 3 Multiple Slide Carousel</h3></div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e477e4/fff&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f566f5/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=7" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=8" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
          interval: 4000
        })

        $('.carousel .item').each(function(){
          var next = $(this).next();
          if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
          }
          next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

          for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
            next=next.next();
            if (!next.length) {
                next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }

            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any one could fix this or any better code.
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://codepen.io/mephysto/pen/ZYVKRY

Comment: @Lalji Tadhani did you tried it in local. it has fault similar to my code. as it is working well on codepen.io but not working good in local

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found what i was looking for.Here is the example working with bootstrap 3.3.x

http://codepen.io/MhSami/pen/zNBMbj

here is source :

```
<style>

    @import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,900,700);

    html {
      font-size: 16px;
    }

    h3 {
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
      font-size: 2.125rem;
      font-weight: 700;
      color: #444;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      margin: 55px 0 35px;
    }

    a {
      color: #ddd;
      text-transform: capitalize;
      font-size: 20px;
      &:hover {
        color: #ccc;
        text-decoration:none;
      }
    }

    .carousel-inner { margin: auto; width: 90%; }
    .carousel-control            { width:  4%; }
    .carousel-control.left,
    .carousel-control.right {
      background-image:none;
    }

    .glyphicon-chevron-left, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
      margin-top:-10px;
      margin-left: -10px;
      color: #444;
    }

    .carousel-inner {
      a {
        display:table-cell;
        height: 180px;
        width: 200px;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
      img {
        max-height: 150px;
        margin: auto auto;
        max-width: 100%;
      }
    }

    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      .carousel-inner > .item.next,
      .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
          left: 0;
          -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
      }
      .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
      .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
          left: 0;
          -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
      }

    }
    @media (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 992px ) {
      .carousel-inner > .item.next,
      .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
          left: 0;
          -webkit-transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
      }
      .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
      .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
          left: 0;
          -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 992px ) {

      .carousel-inner > .item.next,
      .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
          left: 0;
          -webkit-transform: translate3d(16.7%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(16.7%, 0, 0);
      }
      .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
      .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
          left: 0;
          -webkit-transform: translate3d(-16.7%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-16.7%, 0, 0);
      }

    }


</style>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h3>Multiple Item Product Carousel Bootstrap 3.3.6<br><a href="#">Thanks to and Refrence @Maurice and Icons8</a></h3></div>
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="3000" id="myCarousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Color/PNG/96/Plants/pineapple-96.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Color/PNG/96/Plants/paprika-96.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Color/PNG/96/Plants/avocado-96.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Color/PNG/96/Food/banana-96.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Color/PNG/96/Plants/onion-96.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Color/PNG/96/Food/asparagus-96.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Color/PNG/96/Plants/watermelon-96.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Color/PNG/96/Food/eggplant-96.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
</div>


 <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item').each(function(){
          var next = $(this).next();
          if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
          }
          next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

          for (var i=0;i<4;i++) {
            next=next.next();
            if (!next.length) {
                next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }

            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
          }
        });


    });


 </script>
```

Thanks @Ruby for highlighting the problem.

Comment: i adapted this code to work on bootstrap 4, the multi item work but the problem is that item are in column but not in row ,

Answer (score 0):

If you use Bootstrap css version 3.2.0, it will work. Its not working for the newer versions.

```
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```